# Build range with string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, template-literals

I have this statement:

```
var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange("D26:E39");
```

and want to replace it with

```
var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(daGrowaRange);
```

The reason I want to use daGrowaRange is not just cause da name, but that the range is not always the same.

- D is a fixed constant value and never changes
- E is a fixed constant
  value and never changes

BUT

- 26 is dynamic and changes and
- 39 is an offset based on the 26 (in
  this case 13 so 39 = 26+13, but the 13 is a variable value also).

I am sure that I could put this together in some ugly ass way, but I am sick of looking at my crappy code and want to learn how you crackz out there make it nice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to accomplish this task:

```
const dValue = 26;
const eValue = dValue + 13;
const daGrowaRange = `D${dValue}:E${eValue}`;
const destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(daGrowaRange);
```